# Unable to debug and add a breakpoint to my custom javascript file using F12 firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, firefox

I have a JavaScript file which i want to debug and test, so i want to add some breakpoints to it. now i read that i can do so using Firefox F12 tool. so i did the following steps:-

1. i navigate to my application.
2. click on F12.
3. then under "Debugger" tab i can see all the script which are loaded with the ability to add breakpoints to it.

But I can not find a way to write a custom JavaScript and add breakpoints to it.. is this possible ? or the JavaScript need to be already loaded inside the page to debug it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open your console, and use `debugger` as one of your statements and the debugger will stop there;

```
(function(){
    var x = 1;
    debugger;
    console.log(x);
})()
```

Comment: exactly what i am looking for ,, so the secret is with using     debugger; ..thanks

Answer (score 1):

One relevant point:

"You can place a `debugger;` statement anywhere in your JavaScript code. Once the JS interpreter reaches that line, it will stop the script execution, allowing you to inspect variables and step through your code."

**Running a script in your computer**

Normally you would have to run an local apache server to do this.

The other option is run the script with node.js. You have plenty of debug options.

Here you got a excelent tutorial about debugging on Node (called Bug Clinic):

https://nodeschool.io/#workshoppers

Comment: now if i open Firefox F12 tool, then i go to Debugger tab,, click on Ctrl + p then i will be prompted to search for scripts within this page, but in my case i want to write a cusotm script which does not exists...not sure how i can do so ?

Comment: No. You open debug tab prior to execution, and it will stop in the `debugger` command. If it's a script created by you it will be included in the page scripts.

Comment: i did not understand your point, now i did not physically deploy my script inside my asp.net application,, but i want to test it before deploying it ... so is this possible.. i mean now i have the script on my notepad++ but not still not deployed inside my application.. so can i debug using firefox tool ?

Comment: now i can add the script under the console tab and run it.. but under the console tab i am only able to run the script but can not debug it and add breakpoints to it .. did u get my problem ?

Comment: You can run the script with node.js. you have several debug options. What do you think ?

Comment: so using F12 tools this is not possible ? i also have VS 2013 installed on my machine could this be useful ? not sure with node.js how i can navigate to a specific  page and run the javascript against it ?

Comment: In Node you run the script on command line. Like this: `node script.js`. About VS, I'm a linuxer, don't know M$ tools (by the grace of God :D)

Comment: ok i downloaded node.js and it will provide a command link window,, so not sure how i can force it to run the script against  a specific page (which i am able to do using the console tab under Firefox f12,,,) also inside node,js there is not a way to add break points ...